# Mongoose Alternative?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a Mongoose alternative for MongoDB as when I use it in WebMatrix 2, it seems to cause it to crash all the time, but I really like the idea of mongoose, so is there an alternative around?

Answer (score 9):

You can also try [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline), which has been seeing a lot of development lately.  Make sure you use the [MongoDb adapter](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo).

Comment: waterline and sails.js +1

Comment: In waterline, one cannot make use of nested fields, you can only assign an id as a foreign key from another collection document ! it is that difference which pained me a lot ! The style of waterline is more of table based database like mysql !

Comment: @AnkurShah, which is better in almost 90% of the scenarios

Comment: @Normal its not a percentage game! It depends on the type of project, i.e., the kind of queries you make and the size and processing it needs! Always work according to space & time complexity! Or simply try whatever you can, if it works then its fine!

Answer (score 9):

Disclosure: I'm the creator of Camo.

I'd suggest [Camo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camo), which is a class-based ES6 ODM for Mongo.

Some features:

- ES6 based (classes, promises, generators/iterators, etc)
- Supports [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), which is the SQLite-equivalent for Mongo
- Simple schema inheritance

Comment: Is Camo a dead project?  Not seeing much activity in 2017, @srobinson...

Comment: @MatthewAdams you're right that there hasn't been much activity. I just haven't had the time. Looking to find someone to help maintain, which I'll be updating the README to advertise this soon

Comment: Thanks for letting everyone know!